# How to use cin and getline properly in a loop?

Tags: c++

I want to write a program which reads in a line and a character and then print them together iterally. This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string s;
  string a;
  while (getline(cin,s)) {
    cin>>a;
    cout<<s<<a<<endl;
  }
}
```

The first time I input:"abc d" as a line and then "a" as a character and 
the output is "abc da". 
But then I input "abc d" again, it immediately output "abc" without waiting for me to input "a" and then output "abc da". Where is my code wrong?

Comment: That's because after the `>> a` there's an unconsumed newline, which the next `getline` reads as an empty line.  There are many duplicate questions about the same issue.

Comment: What's difference of usage of  `s` and `a` here?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `cin>>a;` there is still a newline in the buffer which is then read by the `getline()`. To avoid this you need to flush the newline out of the buffer. This can be achieved by calling `cin.ignore()` and in some cases `cin.sync()`, although I am not sure of the exact functionality of the `cin.sync()` function.